# Sending back data from activity to already running activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity `Detail` that start a new activity `List` via `Intent`.

In `List` I do stuff and then I need to pass some data back to `Detail`.

The stack, before calling back from `List`, should contain `Detail` (on Pause) and `List` (running).

The data I need to pass back are an `ArrayList<MyObject>`, where `MyObject` implements `Parcelable` (and all its needed methods), so I can use

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("myList", myListOfParcelableObjects);
```

to send data via Intent.

The problem now is on the called activity, `Detail`.

I've tried to catch the new intent via `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` and `onResume(..)` method, but the first (even using `setIntent(intent)`) and the second doesn't get the new intent sent from `List` and the data contained in intent.

How can I get the new intent in `Detail`, manage new datas and "resume" `Detail` as it was before calling `List`?

Comment: Did you use startActivityForResult to start the List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a Singleton Manager save the Data there and use the data when needed.

```
public class DataManager {

    private static DataManager instance = new DataManager();

    private int mData;
    private DataManager() {}

    public static DataManager getInstance() {
       return instance;
    }


    public void setData(int number) {
         mData = number;
     }
   public int getData() {
       return mData;
    }



}
```

**Activity A**

```
DataManager manager = DataManager.getInstance();
manager.setData(1);
```

**Activity B**

```
DataManaget manager = DataManager.getInstance();
int data = manager.getData();
```

this is an Example.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Singleton class for storing common data. Hope it will help.